# symbolically replace expressions in maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm having trouble finding out how to do this:

```
x=a+b
y=c+d
z=x*y
```

I would like the output to be

```
z=ac+ad+bc+bd
```

not

```
z=xy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
(%i1) x: a+b;
(%o1)                                b + a
(%i2) y: c+d;
(%o2)                                d + c
(%i3) z: x*y;
(%o3)                           (b + a) (d + c)
(%i4) z: expand (z);
(%o4)                        b d + a d + b c + a c
(%i5)
```

Assignment in maxima is done by :, not = (which is used for checking for equality)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to get the output he's requesting without assigning a lot of variables, 
you can just do this:

```
(%i1) z = x*y, x = a+b, y = c+d, expand;
(%o1) z = b d + a d + b c + a c
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the canonical solution in my opinion is the subst() function